# smarty разобрать массив

Tags: php, smarty

добрый день, у меня приходит массив двохуровневый  $arr;

```
array (size=2)
  1 => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => string '4c/bb/4cbb2c9798d4fb02d4a078cccb021c5b.jpg' (length=42)
      1 => string 'fd/08/fd084794c82ac7355a2ccc8ee7b55fc0.png' (length=42)
      2 => string 'af/72/af722f16e9447222523d70cd72c770c1.jpg' (length=42)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '83/0b/830be32903bce0779fe36eab55f9bde7.png' (length=42)
      1 => string '76/27/76277945ce8b9b910aa4e9d9e4ed7ed8.jpg' (length=42)
```

Я хочу сделать так: (логика)

```
{foreach $arr[1] as $url}
    <div style="background: url('/media/{$url};"></div>
{endforeach} 

{foreach $arr[2] as $url}
    <div style="background: url('/media/{$url};"></div>
{endforeach}
```

то есть нужно сделать к примеру дивы двох типов: те которые находятся в $arr[1] и вторые $arr[2]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы имеете в виду это?

```
{foreach from=$arr[1] item=url}
    <div style="background: url('/media/{$url};"></div>
{/foreach} 

{foreach from=$arr[2] item=url}
    <div style="background: url('/media/{$url};"></div>
{/foreach}
```